# Floating values changing

Tags: c++, floating-point

i everyone,

I am interested in learning computer graphics algorithms and I am doing a fun little
exercise from here:

http://groups.csail.mit.edu/graphics/classes/6.837/F03/assignments/assignment0/index.html

However, I am having trouble getting my IFS class to take in floating point values
correctly.  Here is the interface:

```
#ifndef _IFS_H_
#define _IFS_H_
#include "matrix.hpp"
#include "Image.hpp"

class IFS 
{
public:
    IFS(const char* filename);
    ~IFS();

    void render(Image& img, int numPoint, int numIterations);
    void printOut();

private:
    int num_transforms;            // number of transformations
    Matrix* matrices;
    float* probablility;

};

#endif
```

Here is the implementation:

```
#include "IFS.h"
#include <iostream>

IFS::IFS(const char* filename){
    FILE* input = fopen(filename,"r");
    assert(input != NULL);

    fscanf(input,"%d",&num_transforms);

    matrices = new Matrix[num_transforms-1];    
    probablility = new float[num_transforms-1];

    float temp;
    for (int i = 0; i < num_transforms; i++) { 
        fscanf (input,"%f",&temp);
        std::cout << temp << std::endl;
        probablility[i] = temp;
        std::cout << probablility[i] << std::endl;
        matrices[i].Read3x3(input);
    }

    fclose(input);
}

IFS::~IFS(){
    delete matrices;
    delete probablility;
}

void IFS::printOut(){
    std::cout << "Number of transformsations: " << num_transforms << std::endl;
    std::cout << probablility[0] << std::endl;

    for(int i = 0; i < num_transforms; i++){
        std::cout << "Number of iterations: " << i << std::endl;
        std::cout << probablility[i] << std::endl;
        matrices[i].Write3x3();
    }
}

void IFS::render(Image& img, int numPoint, int numIterations){
    std::cout << "In Progress" << std::endl;
}
```

Here is my main function:

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>

#define HEIGHT 480
#define WIDTH 640

#include "image.hpp"
#include "matrix.hpp"
#include "vectors.hpp"
#include "utils.h"
#include "IFS.h"


int main(void){
    IFS myIFS("dragon.txt");
    myIFS.printOut();

    std::cout << "Hello world" << std::endl;
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Here is dragon.txt:

```
2
0.5
0.500124 0.499725 -0.250062 
-0.499725 0.500124 0.249863 
0.000000 0.000000 1.000000 
0.5
-0.499327 0.500521 0.749664 
-0.500521 -0.499327 0.750261 
0.000000 0.000000 1.000000
```

And here is the output:

[image: myImage]

I haven't changed any of the starter code from the website.
I can't figure out the problem.  The constructor seems to take in
the probability values correctly. The values change from there to the IFS::printOut()
method.  Does anyone have any idea what is going on?

Comment: Don't use TABs.  And please format & simplify code you post: Leave away the `#ifndef` & `#define` of `_IFS_H_`, remove useless empty lines, ...  Then, describe your problem in more detail because it's unclear to me what you mean (and don't expect others to analyse your code searching for meaning).

Comment: -1 for attaching a screenshot of **text**.

Comment: This question does not show enough effort to narrow the problem down and be concise.


Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not allocating enough space in these arrays.

```
matrices = new Matrix[num_transforms-1];    
probablility = new float[num_transforms-1];
```

You've allocated space for `num_transforms-1` elements, but then you have this code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < num_transforms; i++) {
    fscanf (input,"%f",&temp);
    std::cout << temp << std::endl;
    probablility[i] = temp;
    std::cout << probablility[i] << std::endl;
    matrices[i].Read3x3(input);
}
```

where you're initialising `num_transforms`, so you are going to be overrunning the allocated space.